# Dama Ben Netina story escalation over time - from 100 to 600K

Tags: talmud-gemara

"Kidushin 31a brings [the story of Dama ben Nesina](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/dama-son-of-netina) and his amazing Kibud Av V'Aim which cost him a huge fortune."

It is not clear when the Maaseh has happened, but this famous story is brought in the name of the Tana R' Eliezer (circa 150) in:

1. Yerushalmi Kiddushin 1:7 (circa 400AD) - the price is **100 Dinarim**
2. Midrash Rabah Bamidbar 1:15 (circa 500-1000) - **1000 Dinarim**
3. Bavli Kiddushin 31a (circa 500-600)- **600,000 Dinarim**

**How this escalation / inflation could be explained**?

*This question is not about the story itself -  it is about the Rabbinical story telling thru the times.*

Comment: Telling the story, giving the citations and context for each of the sources, and explaining why you ordered them this way would give potential answerers much more to work with, and probably facilitate better answers.

Comment: This question target the scholars that are closely familiar with the subject. This question is not about the story itself -  it is about the Rabbinical story telling thru the times.

Comment: In the Yerushalmi they raised the offer to 1,000, and in the Bavli there is an alternate version with 800,000. Either way, they probably changed the numbers due to inflation.

Comment: I'm not following the chronology presented here. Shouldn't you list Yerushalmi Bavli then Medrash Rabba? Which would mean there was not a steady increase in the number presented.

Answer (score 5):

Rav Yechiel Michel Feinstein in שיעורי רבנו יחיאל מיכל - בכורות ה. אות צב, answers the differences between the Bavli and Yerusalmi.

Rashi in Bechoros 5a writes that a Kikar is 60 Maneh, and a Maneh is 100 Dinar, so a Kikar is 6000 Dinar.

He suggests that the Bavli was referring to actual Dinarim, which was 600,000. The Yerusalmi was referring to 100 Kikar of Dinarim, which is the same the Bavli.

As far as the general question about discrepancies in stories. Many times they are answered someplace, similar to this answer. Other times there are different versions. In both the Bavli and yerusalmi quoted in the question, there are different versions.

Comment: Why would it refer to Kikarim of Dinarim as Dinarim? Are those units ever even composed with each other? No one talks about having dimes of nickels to mean groups of 50 cents. Do we have evidence elsewhere in contemporary writings of parallel usage?

Comment: @DoubleAA - I"m not sure how they spoke in the times of the Gemorah.

Comment: This is a nice try, thank you. It seems that there's a clear escalation of the same story over the time

Comment: @DoubleAA -  I know that people who order large amounts, such as a restaurant ordering wholesale trays of rolls, might say "please give me 6 rolls" meaning 6 x 50 rolls. Its possible that was the case in the Yerusalmi's version.

Comment: @AlBerko - Are you saying that what actually happened changed?

Comment: Maneh is Dinar. See here, http://www.jewishmag.com/145mag/jewish_coins/jewish_coins.htm

Comment: @joshwaxman -  Rav Feinstein was quoting Rashi "ככר הוי ששים מנה ומנה מאה דינר"

Comment: @joshwaxman - Your source also says it. "Another monetary term written during the Tannaitic and the early Amoraic periods (1st to the 3rd centuries) was the 'maneh' a term, which meant 100 denarii. However, from the third century onwards, it use was referred to a single denarius."

Comment: exactly. I was trying to support your answer, that the meaning of these terms shifted over time.

Comment: @joshwaxman - Sorry. I understood you wrong.